# Number of positive divisors between $a$ and $a^2$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a$ be a positive integer and let $M(a,a^2)$ denote the number of positive divisors of $a^2$ between $a$ and $a^2$, not including $a$. Prove that $M(a,a^2) = \dfrac{\tau(a^2)-1}{2}$ where $\tau(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$.

I tried thinking of a good argument for why this is but didn't find one. Should we use the prime factorization of $a$ in order to help answer this?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be a positive integer. For every divisor $d|n$ with $d<\sqrt{n}$ there is exactly one divisor $\frac{n}{d}$ of $n$ with $\frac{n}{d}>\sqrt{n}$. So the number of divisors $d$ of $n$ with $d<\sqrt{n}$ is equal to the number of divisors $d$ with $d>\sqrt{n}$.

Since $a^2$ is of course a square, it has an extra divisor $a=\sqrt{a^2}$, hence
$$ \tau(a^2)=1+2M(a,a^2) $$

Comment: I think you should point out the converse as well.

Comment: The converse of what?

Comment: You have shown that for every divisor $d$ of $n$ less than $\sqrt{n}$ there is a divisor $\frac{n}{d} > \sqrt{n}$. You also should say what happens if we have a divisor of $n$ greater than $\sqrt{n}$ otherwise there may not be a bijection.

Comment: $\frac{n}{\frac{n}{d}}=d$.